# Laravel - New project, registration page unavailable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm new to laravel and have just created a project(laravel version 5.4.34).

After using:
composer create-project Laravel/Laravel project

and after adding the details for a mysql database connection and running

php artisan make:auth

I browse to the url of the project and get the basic laravel homepage, with the login and register links in the top left.

When i click either the register or the login link, it seems to get stuck in a redirect loop. How would this happen just after installation - would this be a routing problem?

UPDATE after Taylor Foster's comment

app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

routes/web.php

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

I think those are the locations of files. Do I need to add routes for /login and /register myself?

I'm not sure if this is useful, though I have been watching the second beginner laracast and follow instructions on making a new route, and that URL doesn't work either, I add:

```
Route::get('/about', function () {
    return view('about');
});
```

to the routes/web.php

and create a basic page showing a h1 tag saying About, and save it at resources/views/about.blade.php as instructed.

This could be the same issue with the auth problem? I don't get why a standard installation of laravel's routes would simply not work - and ideas/advice would be greatly appreciated.

In case anyone had the same problem as I did when starting out with Laravel, adding:

```
<Directory "/var/www/project/public">
    AllowOverride all
</Directory>
```

within the virtualhost config seems to have solved the problem.

Comment: What do you get in laravel.log when you access the register or login link?

Comment: are you get any error?

Comment: you directly write in your browser localhost:8000/login and see what happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Controllers, there should be `Auth/LoginController.php`. There should be a variable in there `protected $redirectTo`. Just set that to a registered route and see if you are still having the same problem.

Comment: Thanks for your comment - I've updated the questions to show what's in the LoginController.php file, I have tried changing the redirectTo, to '/', assuming this would just redirect to the welcome page. Though I still cannot browse to the register or login pages due to too many redirects. Is this redirectTo just where to redirect the user after they've already logged in? Sadly I can't even get that far. :/

Comment: use a different tool like curl or wget to see what the first redirect is trying to do. Doing this in the browser can happen too quickly to notice.

Comment: Using curl, it showed that it was trying to redirect to the page not found page. Grabbing this from the virtualhost config. I have changed the ErrorDocument in the virtualhost to the root domain, and when browsing to /about it does just redirect back to the welcome page. So would I need to change my virtualhost configuration to allow requests through for laravel controller to handle?

Comment: I think I needed to add:

Comment: <Directory "/var/www/project/public">
        AllowOverride all
    </Directory>

Comment: To the virtualhost, and it seems to be working now. Thanks a lot for all your help

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a permission error, try setting the right permission on your project's directory.

`sudo chown -R :www-data path/to/your_project`

After, `cd path/to/your_project` and run this command so set storage's folder permission:

`sudo chmod -R 775 storage`

Comment: Still the same thing,  one thing I didn't mention - when I first created the project and browsed to it, the laravel page didn't show up due to a load of permissions errors, so I recursively chmod and chown the entire project at that point which let me see the laravel page. I've tried specifying the storage directory specifically and still no luck, just get the too many redirects message from my browser